# Converting a double to exact string in java

Tags: java, string, type-conversion

I have the following double value

```
double d = 123456789.8210000000001;
```

Now I need to convert it to

```
String s = "123456789.8210000000001"
```

exactly.

I used the following code

```
double d = 123456789.8210000000001d;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setGroupingUsed(false);
df.setMaximumIntegerDigits(20);
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(20);
System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

but it gives the output "123456789.821"

When I used the following code

```
double d = 123456789.8210000000001d;
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d);
System.out.println(bd.toPlainString());
```

it gives 123456789.82099999487400054931640625

but I need the exact value.

Note: Here the number of digits in the Integer/fraction part can vary.

Comment: You're *seeing* the exact value that's stored in `d`. Hint: `double d = 123456789.8210000000001d` doesn't store the exact value 123456789.8210000000001, because that isn't representable as a `double`.

Comment: This question shows that you do not understand [floating point numbers](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Answer (score 5):

As soon as you store the value `123456789.8210000000001` in a `double`, your exact representation is lost by the precision of double.

If you want to keep your exact digits, you should use the `String` constructor of `BigDecimal`:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("123456789.8210000000001");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define it as double that change will happen. use `BigDecimal`

```
    BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal("123456789.8210000000001");
    String str=val.toString();
    System.out.println(str);
```

Now you will get the same as `String`

Output:

```
   123456789.8210000000001
```